# loading ArrayList<String> from java properties file

Tags: java, arraylist, properties-file

I'm reading from a properties-file using this method:

```
public void loadConfigFromFile(String path) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(path);

            prop.load(input);

            /*saved like this:*/ //emails: abc@test.com, bbc@aab.com, ..
            String wordsS = prop.getProperty("keywords");
            String emailS = prop.getProperty("emails");
            String feedS = prop.getProperty("feeds");

            emails = Arrays.asList(emailS.split(",")); //ERROR !!
            words = Arrays.asList( wordsS.split(","))); //ERROR !!
            feeds = Arrays.asList( feedS.split(",")); //ERROR !!

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the fields to be written are declared as follows:

```
    private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList("f00@b4r.com", "test@test.com")
    );

    private LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<>(
            Arrays.asList("vuln", "banana", "pizza", "bonanza")
    );

    private LinkedList<String> feeds = new LinkedList<>(
            Arrays.asList("http://www.kb.cert.org/vulfeed",
                    "https://ics-cert.us-cert.gov/advisories/advisories.xml")
    );
```

..so the compiler shows me the following Information, which I don't know how to use:

> Incompatible types. Required `ArrayList<String>` but 'asList' was inferred to `List<T>`: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that `List<T>` conforms to `ArrayList<String>`

How to circumvent this?

Comment: And how are these variables declared?

Comment: @Tom editing...

Comment: So you know the type of `emails` and have you checked what `asList` returns? Does that match? Is the returned type equal or a sup type of `emails` type?

Comment: fixed it by declaring emails as List<String> rather than ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the type of the declared variable that you assign to 
`emails = Arrays.asList(emailS.split(","));`.
According to the compilation error, it is declared as `ArrayList` but `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List`.
You cannot assign a `List` to an `ArrayList` while you can do the reverse.

Besides `Arrays.asList()` return an instance of a private class : `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` that is not the same that the `ArrayList` variable that you declare : `java.util.ArrayList`. So even a downcast to  `ArrayList` would not work and cause a `ClassCastException`.

Change the declared variable from 
`ArrayList<String> emails`  to `List<String> emails` and do the same thing for two other `ArrayList` variables.

Comment: Alternately, if you actually want an `ArrayList` (say, if you wanted to be able to add more things to the List), you can pass the results of `Arrays.aslist` to the [`ArrayList` copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: Nice. Declaring an List-Interface is much more generic than declaring a ArrayList interface. Couldn't figure it out myself, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @Powerlord in any case, it's always better to declare variables as List rather than ArrayList.

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes, it is.